# Powershell script which will detect installed software on clients and servers

Tags: powershell

My powershell module is not working as it should. I have used a [script from Microsoft Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-a-List-of-Installed-c47393ed) which I have modified because as we all know on Windows you can find two different registry paths where the list of the installed software is located.

So here is my psm1 script which when targeted versus different hostnames in our domain always returns the same result, my own PC's software list:

```
Function Get-OSCInstalledApplication
{
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Get-OSCInstalledApplication is an advanced function which can be used to get installed application on local or remote computer.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Get-OSCInstalledApplication is an advanced function which can be used to get installed application on local or remote computer.
    .PARAMETER  ComputerName
        Gets the installed application on the specified computers. 
    .PARAMETER  ComputerFilePath
        Specifies the path to the CSV file. This file should contain one or more computers. 
    .EXAMPLE
        C:\PS> Get-OSCInstalledApplication -ComputerName "Server201201","Server201202"

        This command will list installed application on 'Server201201' and 'Server201202'.
    .EXAMPLE
        C:\PS> Get-OSCInstalledApplication -ComputerFilePath C:\Script\ComputerList.csv

        This command specifies the path to an item that contains several computers. Then 'Get-OSCInstalledApplication' cmdlet will list installed application from thoese computers.
    .EXAMPLE
        C:\PS> Get-OSCInstalledApplication -ComputerName "Server201201" | Export-Csv -Path C:\installedApps.csv

        This command will list installed application on 'Server201201' and saves the strings in a CSV file.
#>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='SinglePoint')]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, ParameterSetName="SinglePoint")]
        [Alias('CName')][String[]]$ComputerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ParameterSetName="MultiplePoint")]
        [Alias('CNPath')][String]$ComputerFilePath
    )

    If($ComputerName)
    {
        Foreach($CN in $ComputerName)
        {
            #test compter connectivity
            $PingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $CN -Count 1 -Quiet
            If($PingResult)
            {
                FindInstalledApplicationInfo -ComputerName $CN
            }
            Else
            {
                Write-Warning "Failed to connect to computer '$ComputerName'."
            }
        }
    }

    If($ComputerFilePath)
    {
        $ComputerName = (Import-Csv -Path $ComputerFilePath).ComputerName

        Foreach($CN in $ComputerName)
        {
            FindInstalledApplicationInfo -ComputerName $CN
        }
    }

    If($ComputerName)
    {
        Foreach($CN in $ComputerName)
        {
            #test compter connectivity
            $PingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $CN -Count 1 -Quiet
            If($PingResult)
            {
                FindInstalledApplicationInfo1 -ComputerName $CN
            }
            Else
            {
                Write-Warning "Failed to connect to computer '$ComputerName'."
            }
        }
    }

    If($ComputerFilePath)
    {
        $ComputerName = (Import-Csv -Path $ComputerFilePath).ComputerName

        Foreach($CN in $ComputerName)
        {
            FindInstalledApplicationInfo1 -ComputerName $CN
        }
    }
}

Function FindInstalledApplicationInfo($ComputerName)
{
    $Objs = @()
    $RegKey = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"

    $InstalledAppsInfos = Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey

    Foreach($InstalledAppsInfo in $InstalledAppsInfos)
    {
        $Obj = [PSCustomObject]@{Computer=$ComputerName;
                                 DisplayName = $InstalledAppsInfo.DisplayName;
                                 DisplayVersion = $InstalledAppsInfo.DisplayVersion;
                                 Publisher = $InstalledAppsInfo.Publisher}
        $Objs += $Obj
    }
    $Objs | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } 
}

Function FindInstalledApplicationInfo1($ComputerName)
{
    $Objs1 = @()
    $RegKey1 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"

    $InstalledAppsInfos1 = Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey1

    Foreach($InstalledAppsInfo1 in $InstalledAppsInfos1)
    {
        $Obj1 = [PSCustomObject]@{Computer=$ComputerName;
                                 DisplayName = $InstalledAppsInfo1.DisplayName;
                                 DisplayVersion = $InstalledAppsInfo1.DisplayVersion;
                                 Publisher = $InstalledAppsInfo1.Publisher}
        $Objs1 += $Obj1
    }
    $Objs1 | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script as it is does query your local computer:

```
 $Objs = @()
 $RegKey = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
 $InstalledAppsInfos = Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey
```

**Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey** refers to the local computer.

The Computername you pass as parameter when calling that function is used only to build a report, which is always referring to your local computer

You need to implement invoke-command and manage the results, or use a precooked script such as [this one](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RemoteProgram-Get-list-de9fd2b4)

Here is a sample implementation

```
$outputfile = "$env:userprofile\Servers_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).log"

$computers = @('host1','host2','host3','host4')
# or
# $computers = get-content HostsListOneperLine.txt
$computers | % {
    write-output "processing $_" # remove if not needed
    if ( test-connection -computername $_ -count 1 -quiet ) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
                Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate 
            }
    }
} | Out-File "$outputfile" -Append
```